# How can I without the 'allow filtering' to have the conditional query in CQL?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am the new leaner in CQL.
I have the (restaurants) table.
By implemented 'desc restaurants', it shows the information in
[restaurants table information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnYdy.png)

How can I run the following query without using 'allow filtering',
`select name from restaurants where borough = 'brooklyn';`

What are the necessary steps in order to be able to run the query without 'allow filtering'?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Cassandra (CQL) you need to take a query-based modeling approach.  This means that you'll need a table specifically-designed to serve queries by `borough`.

A good question to start with, is why (in your current table design) is `id` your sole primary key?  Do you have to support a query by `id`?  If not, then you shouldn't need that table.  However, as `borough` is not unique, it makes sense to cluster an additional column(s) into your primary key definition.

I'd go with something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE stackoverflow.restaurants_by_borough (
    borough text,
    name text,
    id int,
    buildingnum text,
    cuisinetype text,
    phone text,
    street text,
    zipcode int,
    PRIMARY KEY (borough, name, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (name ASC, id ASC);
```

Now this query will work:

```
select name from restaurants_by_borough
where borough = 'brooklyn';
```

It will return data for each borough, sorted by `name`.  Also, if any two restaurants have the same `name` (there's probably more than one McDonalds in Brooklyn) `id` is added to the end of the key to ensure uniqueness.